# Redirect strange URLs with two periods in them

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I had a static HTML website that I recently converted over to drupal.  I have been monitoring my sites 404 errors in webmaster tools and drupal reports and have noticed that google has indexed strange urls. My guess is they came from relative links that were created improperly from the older static HTML site.

Here is an example:
www.example.com/items../item-page.html

The actual page is:
www.example.com/items/item-page.html

The new drupal site doesn't even have .html extensions. I am using URL redirect and path auto modules and have redirects setup for all of the old urls to make sure they are 301'd to the new URL structure (e.g. www.example.com/items/item-page.html would be 301 to www.example.com/items/item-page).

I have access to the server so I am doing my redirects in the apache httpd.conf file instead of .htaccess. I tried the following code to redirect ../ to / but I am not having any luck:

```
RewriteRule ^\.\./(.*) /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This rule doesn't do anything when I go to a url with the ../ in it.  Is there a rewriterule that can match ../ and remove it from any url?

NOTE:  I have other redirects in apache httpd.conf that are working fine...such as:

```
RewriteRule ^items/pdf/(.*)$ /sites/default/files/documents/items/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

So I don't think its my server configuration.

EDIT:
I noticed that the rewrite rule above for rewriting the pdf directory works even with the .. in the URL.  Example:
    http://www.example.com/items../pdf/somedocument.pdf 
redirects to
    http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/documents/items/somedocument.pdf
So it looks like the .. is completely ignored in rewrite rules, which is why I can't get anything to work.  Does anyone know a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe you need to escape your forward slash.
2. I believe rewriterule acts against the HTTP request URI, not the page link.
   Consequently, I believe you will need to remove the carat to find a match, and analyze your intentional URLs to see if that would have a negative impact elsewhere.

Comment: I tried removing the caret and escaping the forward slash (also tried only escaping forward slash with the caret still in place), it still just gives me a 404 and does not redirect.

Comment: Can you see the group one value that results in the 404 (Apache error logs)? Did you omit the full path from the $1 in your real world rule the same as you did above?  e.g. $1 instead of /sites/default/files/documents/items/$1 ?

Comment: No error for this in error.log.  Access.log shows 
    192.168.1.119 - - [09/Aug/2016:09:37:22 -0400] "GET /items../item-page HTTP/1.1" 404 67516
I'm not sure exactly what you mean about omitting the full path.  To clarify, the second Rewrite rule I listed is only to show you that I have other redirects working as intended on my server.  The one I have working is to redirect pdfs from the old file structure to the new file structure in drupal where I store my pdfs.  NOTE: I am testing these redirects on my local development server so thats why IP address is a local ip.

Comment: Can you compare (and preferably paste here) the logged URL from the 404 example above to a logged URL from a 200 example in the standard apache log? Is there a path difference? What happens if you copy/paste the URL from the 404 into your browser? How does that compare to the URL and behavior you expect to receive?

Comment: 192.168.1.119 - - [09/Aug/2016:09:23:07 -0400] "GET /items../item-page HTTP/1.1" 404 67516 
192.168.1.119 - - [09/Aug/2016:09:23:00 -0400] "GET /items/item-page HTTP/1.1" 200 89113

There is no difference between them other than the extra two periods.  The url from the 404 is what I am testing the redirects on already (www.example.com/items../item-page leads to 404, I want it to redirect to www.example.com/items/item-page)

Comment: forword slash is not treated as a delimeter in mode rewrite regex, so there is no need to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
RewriteRule ^/items\.\.(.+)$ /items/$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect **/items..foobar** to **/items/foobar**

Comment: I tried it but still no luck, the url is not rewritten at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was **not** able to fix the issue using rewrite rules in apache due to the rewrite rules not finding ".." in the url for unknown reasons.

My solution was to create a custom drupal module that looks to see if ".." is in the URL.  If the ".." string is found, then I have it set to redirect to the url without ".." in it using built-in drupal functions.  Here is the code I used in my module.

```
function doubledot_fix_init() {
    $destination = drupal_get_destination();
    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($destination['destination']);
    $fixpath = str_replace("..", "", $alias, $count);
    if ($count > 0) {
        drupal_goto($fixpath, array(), 301);
    }
}
```

I do not see any reason this fix will break anything, because ".." should never really be found in any URL.  If anyone can think of a situation that this fix could cause an issue, or if you know of a better solution, please let me know.